# Magento: programmatically changing the related products

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to copy the related products of one product ($odlProduct) to another product ($newProduct). I am doing this because I am trying to create a simple product from a configurable product.

I have used this code:

```
$newProduct->setRelatedProductIds($oldProduct->getRelatedProductIds());
```

I can confirm that the related products have been added:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($newProduct->getRelatedProductIds(), "new product...");
```

I have made sure that the product has been saved using $newProduct->save();

However, nothing shows up in the product page or when I query the related products in PHP.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like following code

```
$param = array(
    101=>array(
        'position'=>3
    ),
    102=>array(
        'position'=>5
    )
);
$_product->setRelatedLinkData($param);
$_product->save();
```

So setRelatedLinkData requires an array which has key as product ID and its value is array [position as key and integer(position) as value].

Comment: Great! Thanks. I couldn't figure it out which method to use. What's the best way to know which function to use? I couldn't find any documentation on Magento webise that lists and explains different methods. Is it fair to say going through the source code is the best way?